# Activate TinyMCE Popup only with Media_Buttons True?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce-4

I'm running Wordpress and TinyMCE in Front-End.

I have one button that opens popup window but it only words with media_buttons TRUE. But i want to hide media_buttons. Thanks in advance.

I get this error:

```
tb_show is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
// quick tags/buttons : link,em,strong,block,del,ins,img,ul,li,ol,code,more,spell,close,fullscreen
// editor styles
$qt = '';
if( $this->options[ 'wpcc_edit_in_html' ] ) $qt = array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,block,del,ul,ol,li,spell,close' );
else {
    $qt = FALSE;
    add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function( '', 'return "tinymce";' ) ); // force visual editor
}
$editor_settings = array(
    'theme_advanced_blockformats' => array( 'h2','h3','p' ),
    'wpautop' => true,
    'media_buttons' => false,
    'tinymce' => array(
        'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,blockquote,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,spellchecker,|,undo,redo,|,mygallery_button',
        'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
        'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '',
        'theme_advanced_buttons4' => ''
    ),
    'quicktags' => $qt
);
```

Here is mygallery_plugin.js:

```
// closure to avoid namespace collision
(function(){
    // creates the plugin
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.mygallery', {
        // creates control instances based on the control's id.
        // our button's id is "mygallery_button"
        createControl : function(id, controlManager) {
            if (id == 'mygallery_button') {
                // creates the button
                var button = controlManager.createButton('mygallery_button', {
                    title : 'MyGallery Shortcode', // title of the button
                    image : 'http://localhost/wpclassificados/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_mrgreen.gif',  // path to the button's image
                    onclick : function() {
                        // triggers the thickbox
                        var width = jQuery(window).width(), H = jQuery(window).height(), W = ( 720 < width ) ? 720 : width;
                        W = W - 80;
                        H = H - 84;
                        tb_show( 'My Gallery Shortcode', '#TB_inline?width=' + W + '&height=' + H + '&inlineId=mygallery-form' );
                    }
                });
                return button;
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    // registers the plugin. DON'T MISS THIS STEP!!!
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('mygallery', tinymce.plugins.mygallery);

    // executes this when the DOM is ready
    jQuery(function(){
        // creates a form to be displayed everytime the button is clicked
        // you should achieve this using AJAX instead of direct html code like this
        var form = jQuery('<div id="mygallery-form"><table id="mygallery-table" class="form-table">\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-columns">Columns</label></th>\
                <td><input type="text" id="mygallery-columns" name="columns" value="3" /><br />\
                <small>specify the number of columns.</small></td>\
            </tr>\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-id">Post ID</label></th>\
                <td><input type="text" name="id" id="mygallery-id" value="" /><br />\
                <small>specify the post ID. Leave blank if you want to use the current post.</small>\
            </tr>\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-size">Size</label></th>\
                <td><select name="size" id="mygallery-size">\
                    <option value="thumbnail">Thumbnail</option>\
                    <option value="medium">Medium</option>\
                    <option value="large">Large</option>\
                    <option value="full">Full</option>\
                </select><br />\
                <small>specify the image size to use for the thumbnail display.</small></td>\
            </tr>\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-orderby">Order By</label></th>\
                <td><input type="text" name="orderby" id="mygallery-orderby" value="menu_order ASC, ID ASC" /><br /><small>RAND (random) is also supported.</small></td>\
            </tr>\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-itemtag">Item Tag</label></th>\
                <td><input type="text" name="itemtag" id="mygallery-itemtag" value="dl" /><br />\
                    <small>the name of the XHTML tag used to enclose each item in the gallery.</small></td>\
            </tr>\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-icontag">Icon Tag</label></th>\
                <td><input type="text" name="icontag" id="mygallery-icontag" value="dt" /><br />\
                    <small>the name of the XHTML tag used to enclose each thumbnail icon in the gallery.</small></td>\
            </tr>\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-captiontag">Caption Tag</label></th>\
                <td><input type="text" name="captiontag" id="mygallery-captiontag" value="dd" /><br />\
                    <small>the name of the XHTML tag used to enclose each caption.</small></td>\
            </tr>\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-link">Link</label></th>\
                <td><input type="text" name="link" id="mygallery-link" value="" /><br />\
                    <small>you can set it to "file" so each image will link to the image file, otherwise leave blank.</small></td>\
            </tr>\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-include">Include Attachment IDs</label></th>\
                <td><input type="text" name="include" id="mygallery-include" value="" /><br />\
                    <small>comma separated attachment IDs</small>\
                </td>\
            </tr>\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-exclude">Exclude Attachment IDs</label></th>\
                <td><input type="text" id="mygallery-exclude" name="exclude" value="" /><br />\
                    <small>comma separated attachment IDs</small>\
                </td>\
            </tr>\
        </table>\
        <p class="submit">\
            <input type="button" id="mygallery-submit" class="button-primary" value="Insert Gallery" name="submit" />\
        </p>\
        </div>');

        var table = form.find('table');
        form.appendTo('body').hide();

        // handles the click event of the submit button
        form.find('#mygallery-submit').click(function(){
            // defines the options and their default values
            // again, this is not the most elegant way to do this
            // but well, this gets the job done nonetheless
            var options = { 
                'columns'    : '3',
                'id'         : '',
                'size'       : 'thumbnail',
                'orderby'    : 'menu_order ASC, ID ASC',
                'itemtag'    : 'dl',
                'icontag'    : 'dt',
                'captiontag' : 'dd',
                'link'       : '',
                'include'    : '',
                'exclude'    : '' 
                };
            var shortcode = '[gallery';

            for( var index in options) {
                var value = table.find('#mygallery-' + index).val();

                // attaches the attribute to the shortcode only if it's different from the default value
                if ( value !== options[index] )
                    shortcode += ' ' + index + '="' + value + '"';
            }

            shortcode += ']';

            // inserts the shortcode into the active editor
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, shortcode);

            // closes Thickbox
            tb_remove();
        });
    });
})()
```

Comment: I just added more information. Hope someone can help me.